# how to read from a GPIO pin when it changes?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I create an app that must detect when the lights(LEDs) changes their status (on->off or off->on) monitor this to a site.I create this app in client side with node.js and use `rpi.GPIO` package from [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rpi-gpio).
But I can't use `change` event in this package
here is my code:

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio');
function alert()
{
    console.log("detected !");
}

gpio.on('change', function(channel, value)
{
    //send monitoring data to server for monitor on site
});
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_IN, alert);
```

`change` event never called !! even if I change the state of LED.
is there any way to do this without use `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this two years old, but in case some people come by for answers.

Notice that in your setup you just specified pin 7 as input and a callback, you need to also specify the edge a pin must trigger an interrupt.

```js
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_IN, gpio.EDGE_BOTH, alert);
```

You can use `EDGE_NONE`, `EDGE_RISING`, `EDGE_FALLING`, and `EDGE_BOTH`, **default is `EDGE_NONE`**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working, but you could also consider [onoff](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff) package.